# how to limit browser back in nextjs after router.push

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im using nextjs build a web app,current I have a confirm page when user click the confirm button I use nextjs router.push method to go to index.what I want to implement is after user
been navigate to index page he can't go back to confirm page using browser back button(when user click browser back button navigate user to some error page) how can i do that.

Comment: you can try `router.replace` instead of `router.push`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the router.replace method, it will replace the current page with the form on it in the browser history stack, and thus clicking the back button will skip over the form route.